# Which Headless CMS to use with Next.js project to ensure speed and security?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, content-management-system, headless

I am working on a project which will have 2 frontends - for customers and for admin.
Admin frontend is to edit the website's content. I want to use Headless CMS with this Next.js project.
As webpage content will be populated with the data from CMS so I need it to be fast. Ofcourse, I will use serversideprops but still speed is the big factor here and also security as admin frontend can change the content at any point of time so it needs to be secure as well.

I expect practical answers from community that which Headless CMS is best for Next.js project.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to speed and security, the most critical to prioritize is **open-source**: you want to make sure you will not rely on a service provider you can neither optimize (speed, performance) nor control (security, data privacy).

[Strapi](https://strapi.io/) should be a great fit for you: it is the most popular open-source Headless CMS (55k stars on GitHub, 10M downloads), you can self-host it (which is great for security), and it is extremely fast (plus you can make it even faster by caching API requests using Redis - https://github.com/strapi-community/strapi-plugin-redis - or a CDN).

Comment: Ok Pierre. Thank you for the great suggestion.

Comment: Hi Pierre,
Now client said that he wants the CMS to store data in mongodb, basically client wants to manage CMS database as well. His exact words were "I want a centralized db". We have implemented Login/SignUp functionality in our app as well. 
Earlier I thought user data will be stored in mongodb and the website content in CMS. But he don't want 2 different data storage units. He want it as one. Also he needs an Admin Panel or Dashboard to edit website content so CMS is a must in that case, Can you suggest something else??